# Log into a site with CasperJS/PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I have the following code to log into iTunesConnect for application development:

```
log.info('login')
account = account || getAccountInfo()
casper
    .open('https://itunesconnect.apple.com/')
    .then(function () {

        log.info('hello itc')
        var _casper = this
        _casper.wait(5000, function () {
          var page = _casper.page,
              i
          for (i = 0; i < account.username.length; i += 1) {
            page.sendEvent('keypress', account.username[i])
          }
          page.sendEvent('keypress', page.event.key.Tab)
          for (i = 0; i < account.password.length; i += 1) {
            page.sendEvent('keypress', account.password[i])
          }
          page.sendEvent('keypress', page.event.key.Enter)

          _casper.wait(1000, function () {})

        })
    })
```

However, for some reason, now the above function is not loading the iTunesConnect page, as it looks like there's a redirect, and I'm not sure how to pass it along. How would I alter the above code to log into iTunesConnect?

Comment: How do you know that it's not loading? I don't see any verification code. Have you taken a screenshot or something? Btw, `page.sendEvent` supports typing strings, so you don't need two loops.

Comment: @ArtjomB. yes, I've taken a screenshot. What will happen is it is stuck on a 'loading' screen.

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: @ArtjomB. -- the log is provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708780/casperjs-phantomjs-chokes-on-loading-a-page

Comment: I've seen that. It's still missing the PhantomJS version and the other 3 event handlers.