# CasperJS/PhantomJS chokes on loading a page

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm running the following script with phantomjs:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var url = 'https://itunesconnect.apple.com/itc/static/login?view=1&path=%2FWebObjects%2FiTunesConnect.woa%3F'

casper.on("page.error", function(msg, trace) {
  this.echo("Error:    " + msg, "ERROR");
  this.echo("file:     " + trace[0].file, "WARNING");
  this.echo("line:     " + trace[0].line, "WARNING");
  this.echo("function: " + trace[0]["function"], "WARNING");
  errors.push(msg);
});



casper.start(url, function(){
    casper.wait(7000, function(){
        // casper.echo(casper.getHTML());
    })
})

casper.run(function() {
  if (errors.length > 0) {
    this.echo(errors.length + ' Javascript errors found', "WARNING");
  } else {
    this.echo(errors.length + ' Javascript errors found', "INFO");
  }
  casper.exit();
});
```

Until a few days ago I could access the page which loads an iframe that contains 2 form fields, to allow user login.

Now I get the following error:

```
Error:    Error: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating '$stateParams.path.startsWith('/')')

    at setupDSiFrame (https://itunesconnect.apple.com/itc/static-resources/controllers/login_cntrl.js?cache=111920151100:99:46)

    at https://itunesconnect.apple.com/itc/static-resources/controllers/login_cntrl.js?cache=111920151100:19:37

    at $digest (https://itunesconnect.apple.com/itc/js/compiled/lib/vendor.js?cache=111920151100:13:11750)

    at $apply (https://itunesconnect.apple.com/itc/js/compiled/lib/vendor.js?cache=111920151100:13:13237)

    at f (https://itunesconnect.apple.com/itc/js/compiled/lib/vendor.js?cache=111920151100:12:56414)

    at r (https://itunesconnect.apple.com/itc/js/compiled/lib/vendor.js?cache=111920151100:12:65848)

    at onreadystatechange (https://itunesconnect.apple.com/itc/js/compiled/lib/vendor.js?cache=111920151100:12:66409)

file:     https://itunesconnect.apple.com/itc/js/compiled/lib/vendor.js?cache=111920151100

line:     12
```

The page loads fine using slimerjs as the engine, but when using slimerjs the login form does not get filled in because the window is not in focus. 
I believe this is an issue where casper is using an old version of WebKit and chokes on loading the page. How would I fix this?

Comment: `0 Javascript errors found` with CasperJS 1.1.0-beta3 and PhantomJS 1.9.8

Comment: @Vaviloff -- right, but that just gives a loading page if you do a screen capture. Could you please verify it works and loads the login screen and not the loading gif?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Too late to solve the problem but maybe useful for future reference if somebody finds the question searching for a problem with `startsWith` in PhantomJS (as I did): [`startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) method was added on the ECMAScript 6 specification, which is not supported by PhantomJS.

A good polyfill for this is [mathiasbynens/String.prototype.startsWith](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/String.prototype.startsWith)